# What event will fire each time a report is previewed/printed?

Tags: events, ms-access, report, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to evauluate the value of a textbox report control and hide or display it based on its value, which I can achieve easily with VBA:

```
If Me.Fixed.Value = 0 Then
    Me.Fixed.Visible = False
End If
```

That works fine, but the query I am using as the report's record source allows a range of records to be printed all at once (1 per page/report), and I want the above code to run for each page/report.  I am unsure of where to put the code so that each record will play by the rules.  Currently, if I choose a range of 8 records, only the first one does what I want, and as I navigate through the other records in the print preview screen the format of the report is remaining unchanged when it should be changing.

I have tried the following events:

*Report:*

- On Current
- On Load
- On Got Focus
- On Open
- On Activate
- On Page

*Section:*

- On Format
- On Print
- On Paint

Where can I put my VBA so that each time I scroll through/navigate the range of records returned on that report my code runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Visible` property back to True as well, otherwise it will remain invisible.

I'm using the Format event of the Details section:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If Me.Fixed = 0 Then
        Me.Fixed.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.Fixed.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This works in Print Preview but not in Report View. There is probably a way to get this to work with the Report View, but I never use this view.

The statement can be simplified:

```
Me.Fixed.Visible = Not (Me.Fixed = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `Visible` property is not available in the `Detail_Paint()` event, which is the event you need to use to have the conditional formatting apply in *Report View*. (Which might be required if you are trying to do something fancy such as simulated hyperlinks for a drill-down effect.)

A workaround is to set the `ForeColor` of the text box to equal the `BackColor`. Although the text is technically still there, it does not "show" on the displayed report, thus simulating a hidden field.

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()
    ' Check for even numbers
    If (txtID Mod 2 = 0) Then
        txtID.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Else
        ' Set to back color to simulate hidden or transparent.
        ' (Assuming we are using a Normal BackStyle)
        txtID.ForeColor = txtID.BackColor
    End If
End Sub
```

Example Output:

[image: Note hidden even numbers]